# Failed to spawn command in atom

Tags: react-native, atom-editor, flowtype

I am getting below error on opening files in atom. Does anyone know what could be the error ?

> Failed to spawn command /cygdrive/c/Users/williams/AppData/Roaming/npm/flow. Make sure /cygdrive/c/Users/williams/AppData/Roaming/npm/flow is installed and on your PATH

Here is the screenshot

[image]

Comment: Obvious question -- does /cygdrive/c/Users/williams/AppData/Roaming/npm/flow exist at that path?

Comment: Either the path given does not exist (for example flow is not installed globally to the npm, or the path doesn't exist), or cygwin installation is faulty, or simply said path is not a part of the PATH. @Williams

Comment: It is there C:\Users\williams\AppData\Roaming\npm and path is also set. I am able to run `flow` command on cmd

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution that works for me
I have Ubuntu 18.04 installed

Solution :

1. Go to Ubuntu Software ( you will find it on taskbar or search in all apps)
2. In store search for xterm and install it.
3. Now after installation, run your code by F5
4. That's it.

Answer (score -1):

Try these two things:

1) Open and run Atom as an administrator
2) Reinstall Atom

You don't mention if this just happened out of nowehere or after installing an extension.

Comment: I run Atom as an administrator and facing same issue. I think it is related to `flow` package

Comment: Probably. I do get some errors or warnings from time to time but I choose to ignore them as they don't affect the code or build.

Comment: It is very strange. It opens on opening javascript file. It covers lot of code editor space. Closing manually again and again is really bad thing